# pass parameters to powershell script from azure automation runbook webhook

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I'm trying to execute an azure automation powershell runbook using the webhook. But, not sure how to pass the parameters to the powershell script.

*PoSh to call webhook*

```
$webhook = "https://ajsiyeqw12-732y-243z-9zashysdg.webhook.us.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=asjfhhye232874829mxsdxbsahfts"
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $webhook
```

*underlying PoSh that has parameters*

```
Param(
 [string]$resourceGroup,
 [string]$VMName,
 [string]$method,
 [string]$UAMI 
)
```

How would we pass the input parameters resourceGroup, VMName etc., to the webhook url to execute the underlying powershell. I am looking to use [management api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/runbook-input-parameters#start-a-runbook-using-the-rest-api-and-assign-parameters) instead for executing the runbook.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/create?tabs=HTTP